# Laravel + tappleby auth token package - Separate controllers?

Tags: authentication, laravel, token

I'm building a Laravel app which also includes an API. I'd like to extend the default Laravel auth scheme to allow api access via tokens. Same auth structure, but two vehicles: api users validated via tokens, web app users validated via Laravel's default auth scheme.
I have a SessionController which I use to login and log out for web app users:

```
<?php

class SessionController extends \BaseController {

public function create() {

    if (Auth::check()) {
        return Redirect::to('/post/dashboard');
    }
    return View::make('sessions.create');

}

public function store() {

    if ( Auth::attempt(Input::only('username', 'password')) ) {
        return Redirect::to('/post/dashboard');
    } else {

        return Redirect::to('/login')->with('error', 'Failed Auth.');
    }

}

public function destroy() {

    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::route('login');
}

}
```

Is it preferred that the api users go through a wholly separate controller for authentication in order to generate and validate tokens? Or can I add the tappleby auth token stuff inside my existing SessionsController and have it serve both purposes?

I'm interested in best practices here.